# Checking jQuery event types

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say, jQuery has `scroll` event type. Is there a chance to determine whether it's assigned an event handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.You can.

```
<input id="fname" type="text"  name="fname" />


$('#fname').change(function(){ alert('change!' );})

if (($.data( $('#fname').get(0), 'events' ).change).length>0)
{
    alert('You have "change" event handler assigned.');
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eFMtU/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.type` to check the event type.

http://api.jquery.com/event.type/